# How to update cell background color of an inactive QTableView/ QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6

My GUI is built by QTableView's.

Each QTableView has a QStyledItemDelegate.

In the QStyledItemDelegate the background color will be changed with:

```
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(ValidatedIntItemDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.backgroundBrush = self.calculate_color_for_column(index)
```

Detail: `self.calculate_color_for_column(index)` just does the validation of the cell value, dependent of the validity, a different color is returned.

All background coloring is working perfect as long I just edit within the same table. If I select a cell in another table, the last selected cell in the old table remains with a grey background not coming from my validation.

Scenario:

- Edit in *Leading edge->a1* value
- Move with Tab or Mouse click to *Leading edge->b1*
- Selected *Trailing edge->a1* cell
- *Leading edge->b1* cell **background is not updated**

[image]

- Not doing any edits in *Trailing edge->a1* select again *Leading edge->x1*
- ALL *Leading edge* cells are shown with **correct background again**!!
- BUT *Trailing edge->a1* has now the wrong background color

[image]

The cells not updating correctly the background color are the ones

- selected
- but in an inactive table/ delegate

So, how to catch this state and make sure the backround reflects the color returned from `self.calculate_color_for_column(index)`?

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing. First of all, it's not clear if by "selecting" you mean that the cell is in editing state (because changed the edit triggers), since you're also mentioning changing cell using the tab, which normally results in going in editing mode for the next cell. In any case, what you're seeing is not the cell background, but the *selection* highlight (which, coincidentally, may be the same background color of the editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is not the background not being updated, but the *highlight* color that is used to show the selection.

In order to ensure that the actual selected item can always be identified, the selection always has the same color, and completely disregards the background of the item. This is probably done for reasons related to UX aspects: for instance, if you use a color with alpha for the selection, you may end up confusing items that are not selected with other that are, but have a color that mixed up with the selection becomes similar to the others.

Since you're using quite pale colors, a possibility could be to use a darker version of the color.

To avoid inconsistency between styles, though, that color won't be used for the item background (the `option.backgroundBrush`) but for the option palette, using the `Normal` and `Inactive` roles with different values of "darkness".

```py
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if opt.backgroundBrush.style() and opt.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            color = opt.backgroundBrush.color()
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Highlight, 
                color.darker(150))
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Highlight, 
                color.darker(125))
```

Another possibility would be what written above: use a *blend* of the background and the palette brush.

Since, as explained, the delegate always ignores the color whenever the item is selected, we need to work around this:

1. paint the basic item primitive `PE_PanelItemViewItem` *without* the `State_Selected` flag, so that it paints the background as expected;
2. alter the opt palette in `initStyleOption()` and change the alpha of the `Highlight` roles;
3. call the base implementation, which will paint *over* the previously drawn background;

```py
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if opt.backgroundBrush.style() and opt.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            normal = opt.palette.color(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Highlight)
            normal.setAlphaF(.5)
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Highlight, normal)
            inactive = opt.palette.color(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Highlight)
            inactive.setAlphaF(.5)
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Highlight, inactive)

    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        # we should *never* change the option provided in the arguments when
        # doing painting: that option is always reused for other items, and 
        # its properties are not always cleared
        vopt = QStyleOptionViewItem(opt)
        self.initStyleOption(vopt, index)
        widget = opt.widget
        style = widget.style()
        if vopt.backgroundBrush.style() and vopt.state & style.State_Selected:
            vopt.state &= ~style.State_Selected
            style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_PanelItemViewItem, vopt, qp, widget)

        # now we *do* use the original option
        super().paint(qp, opt, index)
```

Comment: The first solution does exactly the work I was looking for. After playing a little bit with the ```color.darker(125))``` values I have a pretty nice solution.  Thank you!